# Convert values in DataFrame to percent by both columns and rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `DataFrame` with two levels for both index and columns

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["A", "B"], ["AA", "BB"]])
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["X", "Y"], ["XX", "YY"]])

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4],
                   [5,6,7,8],
                   [9,10,11,12],
                   [13,14,15,16]], index = index, columns = columns)
```

I would like to convert values in this `DataFrame` to percents in such a way that I can pass level of both index and column and the corresponding "square" will be converted to percents. To be more precise, I would like to pass `rowLevel = 0` (which corresponds to `A` and `B` index values) and `colLevel=0` (which correspond to `X` and `Y` column values) and as a results I should get

```
res = pd.DataFrame([[1/14,2/14,3/22,4/22],
                   [5/14,6/14,7/22,8/22],
                   [9/46,10/46,11/54,12/54],
                   [13/46,14/46,15/54,16/54]], index = index, columns = columns)
```

It should also works  for higher `rowLevel`'s and `colLevel`'s. How can I do that in a most elegant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["A", "B"], ["AA", "BB"]])
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["X", "Y"], ["XX", "YY"]])
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4],
                   [5,6,7,8],
                   [9,10,11,12],
                   [13,14,15,16]], index = index, columns = columns)


def f(df, rowLevel, colLevel):
    res = df.copy()
    index_levels = df.index.get_level_values(level=rowLevel)
    columns_levels = df.columns.get_level_values(level=colLevel)
    for i in set(index_levels):
        for j in set(columns_levels):
            idxi = index_levels == i
            idxj = columns_levels == j
            res.loc[idxi, idxj] /= res.loc[idxi, idxj].sum().sum()
    return res

rowLevel = 0
colLevel = 0
res = f(df, rowLevel, colLevel)
print(res)
```

prints

```
             X                   Y          
            XX        YY        XX        YY
A AA  0.071429  0.142857  0.136364  0.181818
  BB  0.357143  0.428571  0.318182  0.363636
B AA  0.195652  0.217391  0.203704  0.222222
  BB  0.282609  0.304348  0.277778  0.296296
```

works for any combination of levels (here aided with color-coding by groups):

```
from IPython.display import display
pd.set_option('precision', 2)

def colorcode(x, rowLevel, colLevel):
    colors = ['brown', 'purple', 'gray', 'olive']
    x_colored = x.copy()
    index_levels = x.index.get_level_values(level=rowLevel)
    columns_levels = x.columns.get_level_values(level=colLevel)    
    m, n = len(set(index_levels)), len(set(columns_levels))
    for a, i in enumerate(set(index_levels)):
        for b, j in enumerate(set(columns_levels)):
            idxi = index_levels == i
            idxj = columns_levels == j
            color = colors[a + b * n]
            x_colored.loc[idxi, idxj] = f'background-color: {color}'
    return x_colored

for rowLevel in [0, 1]:
    for colLevel in [0, 1]:
        mat = f(df, rowLevel, colLevel).astype(float).round(2)
        display(
            mat.style.apply(
                lambda x: colorcode(x, rowLevel, colLevel),
                axis=None
            )
        )
```

displays

[image: img]

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Just one more question: if we look at second image from the bottom from your answer (for `rowLevel = 1`  and `colLevel = 0`) then we have 4 colours. For example for `red` color we have 4 values (which sum is 1) for which `rowIndex == BB` and `colIndex == X`. What if I would like to print separate percentages for `(A, BB)` and `(B,BB)` indices so that for each of them the values sum to 1? Ideally I woul like to pass `rowLevel = [0,1]` and `colLevel=0` to obtain such an effect. Is it possible? So instead `(0.13, 0.16, 0.34, 0.37)` I'd like to get `(5/11, 6/11, 13/27, 14/27)`

Comment: Yes it is possible